# Replace for loop that indexes two arrays and applies a function on each row

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, numpy

I have a for-loop that works on two values and I would like to apply it in a faster way or vectorise it if possible. My original for-loop looks something like this

```
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3]
y = [0,0,0]

for i in range(len(x)):
    
    # index value in each element
    xi = x[i]
    yi = y[i]
    
    # apply function some bivariate function
    print(np.sum(xi,yi))
```

I was thinking maybe I could use the list approach but the output came out as below.

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = [0,0,0]

[np.sum(i, j) for i in x for j in y]
```

```
# output
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

What are better methods to replace the initial for-loop statement? My actual function is not a sum as in the initial example, that is just a dummy function.

Comment: What is your actual function?

Comment: My actual function is `datetime.datetime.combine`

Comment: combine a date and a time object or strings?

Comment: Yes, but the data was messy so I had to wrangle it before hand, I thought that it'd be better to create a simple example to post.

Comment: No, post a sample of your real data, it will be better with particular case

Comment: Ok, I will prepare it and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use `zip`

```
>>> [np.sum(i, j) for i, j in zip(x, y)]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you. Would this be the fastest way to do this?

Comment: It depends on your function.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. - Use the `zip` function in such cases

```
list_sum = [np.sum(x,y) for x,y in zip(x,y)]
```